# Multiple values for rel attribute

Tags: html

Can I have multiple values for rel attributes? Like so:

```
<a href="#" rel="value1 nofollow">Link</a>
```

.. is it valid and cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[It's valid.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel)  I'm not sure if it's supported by all browsers, though, but I would guess that it is.

> rel = link-types [CI]
>   This attribute describes the relationship from the current document to the anchor specified by the href attribute. The value of this attribute is a **space-separated list** of link types.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't make assumptions in web design - especially regarding browser support...

Comment: Well, in this case the important thing is to have crawler support ;-)

Comment: Valid. How else would you be able to tell a search engine that some link is "nofollow" and _at the same time_ signal a browser "noopener" for JS security reasons...

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's valid and it works on all browsers, including IE7 and IE8

Answer (score 5):

***Definitely valid.***

You can also do the same thing with  the class attribute. This is handy for CSS styling.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="foo bar more classes">Stuff</span>
<span class="bar">More bar</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo{
  color: #afafaf;
}

.bar{
  border: 1px solid #0ff;
}
```

The first span would be gray and have the blue border, while the second span would just have the border.

Comment: You can't actually add multiple values to the id attribute, nor can you put spaces in the id value. The id of a HTML Element is a 1 to 1 relationship, therefore each value can only occur once per page.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can and it's valid: e.g: `rel='tag nofollow'`

```
<a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag nofollow'><data:label.name/></a>
```

just use values with giving "blank space" among them. The complete details of tags used inside rel are here..

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually it isn't valid according to Structured Data Testing Tool.

I tried this tonight, using the following

```
rel="publisher nofollow"
```

and it failed to validate the publisher. As soon as I removed the nofollow is validated ok again.

I thought I would post my answer, as I came across this thread after doing a Google search for the same question.

Comment: Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't report as invalid now.

Comment: @StevenVachon Strutctured Data Testing Tool doesn´t care about rel anymore. It ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with jQuery Mobile and it doesn't work. It works if I remove the second attribute.

```
rel="external nofollow"
```