# Can I mix and match rel attributes?

Tags: html, seo, semantics, rel

I'm a little confused by the `rel` attribute usage.

Individually I understand `rel="author"`, `rel="me"` and `rel="publisher"`, however I am wondering if I can mix and match attribute values.

Example 1: On [my website](http://iancrowther.co.uk), I have a link in the footer which links to my domain.  Do I add `rel="me"`, `rel="author"` or `rel="me author"`?

Example 2: On [my website](http://iancrowther.co.uk) I have a link to my twitter account. Do I add `rel="me"` or `rel="me publisher"`?

Comment: Multiple rel values may be used: http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-faq#How_is_rel_used

Comment: Thanks for the link - I have now read the manual! :)

Comment: If you use rel="author nofollow" with Google Authorship, Google Authorship stops working. So although it is valid markup to mix and match, this particular combination doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple values for rel attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878657/multiple-values-for-rel-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add more than one rel attribute into one HTML element, but you can insert more than one argument into one rel attribute value - just delimit them with a space:

```
<a rel="me author" href="my_page">
<a rel="me publisher" href="twitter_link">
```

Comment: @iancrowther only if you use values that would naturally be conflicting. `me author` is fine since you can be the author, but `prev next` wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I looked the Google rich snippet tool complained if you had both author and publisher mark-up on the same page.

If I remember correctly, author beats publisher

Comment: Hey Tiggerito, thanks for doing the check.  I think i have the rel's sorted now.  THe site is very much in flux at the moment so