# jquery tooltip from html title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying [jQuery Tooltip from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), which requires quite a few extra attributes:

```
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Hello" href="#">Tooltip Example</a>
```

There seems to be a bit of a problem with this though, because I use rel="nofollow" on quite a few URLs I want to use tooltip on, and it doesn't let me use both at once.

Even more important, I want an elegant fallback for users that don't have JavaScript enabled browsers.

I want to know if there's a way I can have jQuery Tooltip treat `title=""` attribute as `data-original-title`, and have a default preset for `data-placement`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhGT3/

Comment: ca you please create and share a fiddle of the same on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Added the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhGT3/

Comment: Your markup appears to be from an older version of Bootstrap. The current tooltip plugin only requires two attributes, like this: `data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!"`. And though you don't need it here, it's worth noting that the `rel` attribute accepts multiple values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878657/multiple-values-for-rel-attribute

Comment: You could even mimic the tooltip with CSS 3 and only use JS when CSS 3 is not supported ... (modernizr). You can extract the tooltip text [data-original-title] {content: attr(data-original-title);  }

Comment: I know rel accepts multiple, but for some reason when I used rel="nofollow tooltip" it didn't work. But is there some way I can have it just treat all content with the title="" attribute as tooltip instead of adding data-toggle="tooltip" as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course there is. you just add title="" and it will pick the text as tooltip.

```
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="my title" 
data-original-title="Hello" href="#">Tooltip Example</a>
```

Here's a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/FhGT3/4/

Also for your second question: Yes, you can set a default preset for data-placement. You just need to specify "data-placement:'

Thanks!

Comment: I meant, is there a way the script can be modified to set a default data-placement, and have it interpret title="" as data-original-title="". I'd like to omit the attributes.

Comment: I want to exclude the rel="" as well. Could something like this work: `function showtooltip() {
    $('a[title="*"]').tooltip({` Like a wildcard for all hyperlinks with title attribute?

Comment: yes, just use **a[title]** as selector and that's all you need!

fiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call tool tips directly. Lets say you give all the `<a>` tags you want to have tool tips a class `runtooltip`

```
<a href="runtooltip" class="runtooltip" rel="nofolow" title="My Tip!">Something</a>
```

just before the `</body>` you have

```
<script>
$('.runtooltip').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var options = {
        placement: 'top'
    }
    $this.tooltip();
});
</script>
```

you can see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8gQ7L/