# rel=preload for stylesheet isn't applying the styles once downloaded

Tags: css, google-chrome, preload

I'm trying out `rel=preload` for the first time, using it for a couple of stylesheets. Here is the code in question:

```
<link rel="preload" href="css/styles.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="//allyoucan.cloud/cdn/icofont/1.0.0beta/css/icofont.css" crossorigin="anonymous" as="style">
```

I'm testing in Chrome 61, and I can see that the stylesheets are downloaded as expected, however they're never actually applied, and I get the message on the console saying that a preloaded resource isn't being used.

If I remove the `rel=preload` in favour of just `rel=stylesheet`, then it works perfectly fine.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you include `<link rel="stylesheet">` for each of them as well? Preloading isn’t really useful on stylesheets like that because they’re already in the `<head>` anyway.

Comment: Oh right, I somehow missed that in the online examples.. Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to have 2 lines for each one with rel=stylesheet and one with rel=preload. As preload is just fetching it and not applying.

However you will probably not notice much performance improvement as it hits one line just before the other.

The better option is to inline the css ([see here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/InlineCSS)) that is seen above the fold then use javascript to add in the in the css file on page load ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913426/33)).

Comment: Same answer here that I replied to Ryan in the comment.
I've only got a small application so there probably isn't much point trying to use preload at all.. Thanks for the in depth answer

Comment: I agree all depends on the application, I have seen significant savings doing this on large applications but it is quite a bit of work to keep it manageable.

Answer (score 57):

What do you think about this approach:

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

Resource: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html

Comment: Despite its inline js nature, I find this to be most in line with DRY and therefore I consider it a more elegant solution than the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for this. It's beautiful.

Comment: Only issue I see is that it jumps a bit on load. Might be that I need to inline my header style

Comment: This won't work in Firefox, like @John says, you need both rel="preload" and rel="stylesheet"

Comment: Also won't work in IE11 or pre-chrome Edge, in case you need to support those https://caniuse.com/link-rel-preload

Answer (score 21):

Technically, you can specify [multiple values for `rel` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1878657/11613622). Something like this should do the job, without writing 2 lines per stylesheet:

```html
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can verify this using Lighthouse. This was result on my browser (there was no chained request as stylesheet was preloaded, and was properly applied):

[image: lighthouse audit]

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks a lot for sharing! Like it much more than inline applying JS :)

Comment: Works in the browsers I care about. Thanks!

Comment: is `crossorigin` required for stylesheets?

Comment: Thanks a ton.. let me give a try..

Comment: According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889123/1191147) this solution doesn't work, and it's not that old either. Are you sure you're reading Lighthouse correctly?

Comment: @HashimAziz that answer looks like it has outdated information, it seems to contradict [MDN's "rel" docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel). In my case, this does fix the Lighthouse warning about critical request chaining.

Comment: This is my preferred solution as it is clean and avoid duplications

Comment: Note that `type="text/css"` is rarely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct but not very clear. For one file, you need 2 lines, and not one:

```
<link rel="preload" href="css/styles.css" as="style"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

I used this approach mostly because of css **background images**. Apparently this will speed up the loading.

---

You can see this approach in a similar fashion for google fonts links:

```
<link rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com'> 

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Serif+Pro:wght@300&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>
```

It's also useful for **fonts**. [See Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload)

Comment: I don't think it's correct to use 2 `link` tags to load 1 resource. They are completely two different things. First one (`rel="preload"`) is not render-blocking. But the second one is. So when the browser encounters with the `rel="stylesheet"`, will block rendering until it is loaded.