# How to use both rel="preload" and rel="stylesheet" for the same tag?

Tags: css, preload, google-pagespeed

Google Pagespeed test doesn't recognize preload when it is used together with stylesheet. I tried

```
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/style.css" />
```

and it still shows "Consider using  to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load.". If I remove stylesheet from rel attribute, it recognizes the preload.

I was thinking to try this:

```
<link rel="preload" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/style.css" />
```

but I am not sure if you can have 2 the same attributes for the same link tag. Would this work?

Comment: You have to declare it twice - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: Note: the `<llink>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load CSS Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759272/how-to-load-css-asynchronously)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rel-preload-for-stylesheet-isnt-applying-the-styles-once-downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787921/rel-preload-for-stylesheet-isnt-applying-the-styles-once-downloaded?rq=3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For loading CSS styles asynchronously, **you should indicate it as a preload stylesheet**. **Whenever you use `rel="preload"` alone, it won't transform to stylesheet on page load. It will remain as `preload`**, so to indicate it as a stylesheet, you should use another attribute such as `as`, which **indicates the type of element; in your case, it should be `style`**. Then you need to tell the browser when the loading process is finished **You need to consider this a stylesheet, so you have to define another attribute like `onload` and then define its real relation**.

So you have to import it like this:

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
```

**NOTE:** You can read more about it in [web.dev](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/).

## Update 2024

#### Basic Usage of `preload`

Thanks to @Hewlett, we have an update regarding browser support for `preload`. According to [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-preload), the [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) feature is now widely supported across all major browsers. This development makes `<link rel="preload">` a reliable choice for prefetching resources without immediately executing them. For preloading stylesheets, the basic implementation would look like this:

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
```

#### Applying Preloaded Stylesheet

However, as highlighted by @MichaelFreidgeim, and per [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload), `preload` merely prioritizes downloading and caching the resource; it doesn't directly apply the stylesheet. To ensure that a preloaded stylesheet is utilized as a `stylesheet` once loaded, a JavaScript-based solution is ideal. This method allows us to preload the stylesheet, reducing its initial render-blocking impact, and then to apply it after the full page load.

Implement it as follows:

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://www.example.com/style.css" id="preloadStyle">
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var preloadLink = document.getElementById('preloadStyle');
    preloadLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
  });
</script>
```

In this setup, the `<link>` tag initially preloads the stylesheet with `rel="preload"`. The JavaScript snippet is designed to wait for the `window.load` event, which is triggered when the entire page, including all dependent resources, is fully loaded. Once this event occurs, the script changes the `rel` attribute of our preloaded link to `stylesheet`, thus applying the styles to the page. This approach strikes a balance between efficient resource loading and optimal rendering performance.

### Handling Specific Positioning in DOM

In cases where you need to preload stylesheets but append them at a specific position in the DOM, you can utilize JavaScript to dynamically insert the stylesheet after its preload phase. This method is especially useful when you want to maintain a specific load order for your styles. For instance, to preload a stylesheet and insert it below an existing style tag, you can do the following:

```html
<!-- Your first style tag -->
<style id="firstStyle">
    /* Your CSS here */
</style>
<!-- Preload your CSS file -->
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://www.example.com/style.css" id="preloadStyle">
<script>
  function loadAndInsertStyle(href, insertAfterId) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = href;
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';

    var ref = document.getElementById(insertAfterId);
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(link, ref.nextSibling);
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    loadAndInsertStyle('http://www.example.com/style.css', 'firstStyle');
  });
</script>
```

This method ensures that your stylesheet is preloaded and then inserted in the desired position within the DOM, allowing for more granular control over stylesheet loading and application.

### Previous Update(obsolete)

Since **`preload` is not supported in Firefox** until now (according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)), the only way to do it is to declare it twice in one `rel` tag or two separate tags.

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
```

<s>Or</s>

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" rel="preload" as="style" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
```

**NOTE:** As @JohnyFree tested the second one *(one with a line through)* in the Google page speed, it won't be recognized as a valid `preload` style, whilst the format is correct according to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html).

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand, which way should I use in order to allow Google PAgespeed to recognize it as valid and also to allow old browser to download the stylesheet?

Comment: It looks to be supported in Firefox now.

Comment: Should example in Update 2023 also have onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" ?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Currently, most browsers support `rel="preload"` so there is no need to use `onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"`, but if, in any case, you want to make sure the content is `preload` ed, you can use it as an extra step.

Comment: You still need to have instruction to use it  as stylesheet. According to  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload “ Even though the name contains the term load, it doesn't load and execute the script but only schedules it to be downloaded and cached with a higher priority.”

Comment: @SMAKSS How do you handle a case where you need to preload stylesheets but append at specific position in DOM.

In my case I have two tags under head. first style and the link. I want to preload link but want to have it below style tag.

Comment: @AmitMankotia, I have added another section *(Handling Specific Positioning in DOM)* to my answer that will answer your question with a general approach.

Answer (score 0):

preload  https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" href="http://www.example.com/style.css"/>
```

fallback for not supported browsers https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" href="http://www.example.com/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you need to do this ***Javascript circus trick*** to save a few hundred milliseconds, I recommend the version below. Use it instead if you want cross-browser support:

```
<link media="print" onload="this.media='all'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Why does this work? In nearly all browsers going back to the 1990's, support of linked "print" media type style sheet was universally supported. Linked print style sheets were only used when printing pages. Because browsers knew the "sheet" media type must always be downloaded before "print", they often delayed or downloaded sheets with "media=print" asynchronously. Nothing was needed by the page author. It has worked this way for many years in most browsers, naturally.

Recently, developers trying to follow Google's new ranking policies discovered this trick to stop some styles from blocking others or from downloading immediately. They then realized the "print" media type was the only built-in, cross-browser way to fool browsers into delaying downloading of style sheets.

Turning your style sheet into a "print" type using the trick above doesn't mean its "print", as the script later changes it back to "all". It is simply a "hack" or way to prevent modern browsers from downloading your CSS styles in parallel with other sheets.

Note: **"all" is not supported in a wide range of older browsers including Internet Explorer versions 1-7**, so a bad idea, anyway.

Stopping one or two style sheets from blocking another sheet from downloading would be the only reason to use this trick, and assumes you are using a HUGE style sheet that is 50+ kilobytes in size and use a server with slow connections.

RECOMMENDATIONS?

**I recommend you do NOT ever "preload" CSS for the following reasons!**

1. Just because Google flags this as an issue in Lightspeed, doesn't mean filling your webpages up with duplicate style links and elaborate JavaScript hacks to shave off a 100 milliseconds is a good idea. **You should care more about the quality and integrity of your HTML pages above all other concerns, including speed or advertising-driven search engine demands**!
2. There could be racing issues! What happens when your HTML downloads before your async "print" sheet resolves itself back to "all"? You may see a flash in some browsers where the HTML downloads first and rendering begins before the async styles are downloaded. Your user then sees your website layouts and fonts move or shift. Nasty!!
3. Async'ing CSS is kinda pointless compared to these poorly designed Javascript frameworks kids are downloading in 2021 that waste download times anyway. Most style sheets are 50 kilobytes or less in size compared to the MASSIVE 500-1500+ kilobytes most modern Javascript frameworks shove into the browser today (ie. React, Angular, Ember, etc.). These downloads often "embedd" the same CSS over and over into the browser's cache anyway, forcing a reload of the same CSS each site visit unlike CSS linked styles which can be cached for months! So preloading linked CSS makes no sense if its reloaded every visit. So what is the point?
4. Many browsers may crash and burn with this trick! The `preload` is not widely adopted anyway, so you run a huge risk in a percentage of your users
   seeing an unstyled web site if you use this "hack". Imagine 5%-10% of your users seeing your website displayed in the default 'Times Roman' font and a white block-level, unstyled content page because you wanted to save 500 milliseconds of download time? Sorry, not worth the risk!
5. Most old browsers had only 2 open connections allowed when downloading files, so they were limited by open connections, not style sheet downloads. Many modern browsers have 6 maximum. So again, connections are the bottleneck here when combined with multiple open JavaScript calls, not style sheet downloads. So little is gained using this trick.
6. Slow Servers are Often the **REAL** Bottleneck: Server delays on opening connections on the server can be huge bottlenecks. Even if your host provider or web application like Wordpress is using cached images, pages, and proxies but your waiting hundreds of milliseconds for a connection to open up on the server, all that becomes meaningless. CDN's can also fail, be delayed, blocked, etc., too.
7. The number one factor delaying downloads, besides slow servers and giant JavaScript API libraries, is more often **huge image files**. Consider using new HTML5 'picture' elements with multiple image types like "WebP" that are highly compressed. If you page has "on-demand", non-streaming video, that also must be set to preload or download asynchronously. Adding "width" and height" values to force 'alt' attribute placeholders, as images download will create reserved dimensions in your page layouts so they don't shift waiting images to download. You will be amazed at the savings in download times and bottlenecks prevented when you focus on image and media issues, not CSS.

All that makes preloading CSS pretty worthless as far as website improvements. I would go look at the multiple Bootstrap, JavaScript modules, and JQuery file downloads stacked up in your browser grabbing limited, shared browser connections and focus on less scripts. 30 or so kilobytes of CSS will likely not be the issue.

Comment: it's supported by every browser,  unless your audience is in the poorest africa countries...

Comment: "preload" is not supported in any Internet Explorer version, Triton Edge, and many other older browsers pre-2010. You have to consider those or you limit your audience.

Comment: I use totally outdated browsers with outdated OS and i'm like an alien already. The browsers are from 2017 at worst and many sites are unusable. Imagine using something pre 2010, it makes no sense and it's totally unusable, just think about it. I can only see this happen in outdated companies and this is not the audience of anybody.

Comment: It happened to me not long ago at a MAJOR corporation that had a projector PC with IE6 installed. Luckily, I had added fixes to our project for the IE6 broken box model. If you don't prepare you will crash and burn.

Answer (score -2):

Firefox has supposedly enabled "preload" in version 85, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. What I found that this code below works:

```
<link rel="preload stylesheet" as="style" href="style.css">
```