# How to use `preload` with a fallback

Tags: javascript, html, css

After googling a lot I still didnt find a way to correctly fallback the usage o `<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />`.

I used Google PageSpeed Insights and it tells me to use `rel="preload"` to some resources, and indeed it works quite well! But for browsers that dont support it, how do I fallback? I cant just:

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" as="style" />
```

Cause the browsers that support `preload` will first know it has priority and later try to download it in another thread, paralizing it: depending on the situation, the browser may download it twice.

After searching a lot at Google I still cant find a way to use the `preload` feature reliably in such way that it optimizes for browsers that support it and in such a way it does not break the website on browsers that dont support it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use both rel="preload" and rel="stylesheet" for the same tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889044/how-to-use-both-rel-preload-and-rel-stylesheet-for-the-same-tag)

Comment: The problem is that link does not provide a valid answer that is acceptable by current situation of Google as, the person that replied, told himself that google does not recognize as valid that provided answer.

Comment: You should stick with the first approach, in the updated version. So you have to declare your `<link>`s twice.